# Helptexts lost when referencing a COM DLL

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, com

I barely have any knowledge of COM, but I will try to make the question as clear as possible.

I have a .NET 4.0 project and am referencing an older COM DLL written in VBScript.

When I use this DLL in the code, I don't get any custom helptexts in VS2010 describing the methods and classes. They are also not available in the object browser.

I guess this has something to do with the automatic wrapper that is applied by .NET to the COM library. The help texts seem to get lost in the process.

When I view the dll directly in the object browser of VS, I can see the texts for methods etc.

Is there a way to keep the describing texts for coding with the referenced COM dll?

Comment: Pretty fundamental compat problem, .NET doesn't have a way to embed IntelliSense info in an assembly.  It is supplied through a separate .xml file.  The type library importer (tlbimp.exe) doesn't have a way to convert the embedded help attributes to an IntelliSense .xml file.  Would be useful, you could perhaps post it as a suggestion here: http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/17579

Comment: This is the default importer .NET/VS uses?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the inline help documentation available for .NET classes rather than parameter type information? If so I share your frustration. I went to a lot of effort to write helpstring comments in my IDL for the benefit of C# programmers consuming my COM object via COM interop to find that none of them survived type library importing.

There is an explanation of this behaviour in Adam Nathan's book ".NET and COM: The Complete Interoperability Guide" under "FAQ: Why doesn't the type library importer save the helpstring contents in DescriptionAttribute automatically?". I've found this book very helpful for learning about COM interop, despite its age. It's also available to buy in Kindle, epub and pdf formats.

Adam Nathan's explanation is that helpstring attributes are not translated into [System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) objects because DescriptionAttributes are meant for Windows forms controls and are not localizable.

Peronally, I'd still prefer that helpstring attributes were translated anyway. Perhaps that feature could be added to the codeplex type library importer linked above if it doesn't do it already.